# How does "Account Fingerprint Phrase" work?

Tags: security, encryption

In bitwarden's [Account Fingerprint Phrase](https://bitwarden.com/help/article/fingerprint-phrase/) page, it says:

> Your fingerprint phrase is an important security feature that assists
> in uniquely and securely identifying a Bitwarden user account when
> important encryption-related operations are performed (such as
> sharing).
>
> Some Bitwarden procedures (e.g. adding a new user to an Organization,
> enabling Biometric Unlock for Browser Extensions) may ask you to
> verify that the fingerprint phrase matches your own or another user’s.
>
> Validating fingerprint phrases ensures that end-to-end encryption is
> securely initiated and that the Bitwarden server you are communicating
> with (and your connection) has not been maliciously tampered with.

So, I guess it is a more secured mechanism to uniquely identify an user. But I am not understanding why it is more secured and how does it work.

Please help me understand it.

Comment: Just to clarify your current understanding, "more secured" than what?

Comment: I have been thinking about your question for last 10 minute or so. What they said is "uniquely and securely identifying a Bitwarden user account". As this tool is used to manage passwords, I just took it for granted that it is more secured than other user identification mechanisms. To tell the truth, I am not sure what to compare this with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to notice is that the fingerprint isn't something you *type*, it's something you *read*:

> Some Bitwarden procedures ... may ask you to verify that the fingerprint phrase matches your own or another user’s.

In a sense, it's like a reverse password: it's something that *you already know*, and the *server has to send you*. If an attacker tries to impersonate the Bitwarden server, they won't know the correct fingerprint phrase to show you, and you can spot the deception:

> Validating fingerprint phrases ensures that ... the Bitwarden server you are communicating with (and your connection) has not been maliciously tampered with.

As well as directly intercepting communications, the fingerprint can protect against potentially damaging typos. Have you ever received an e-mail intended for someone whose address is similar to yours, because of a typo? Imagine accidentally sharing your passwords with user "bobsmith" instead of "bob.smith". If your friend Bob can tell you or confirm their account's fingerprint phrase (over the phone, for instance), you can be much more certain that you've selected the right account to share with.

In an ideal world, the fingerprint would be a long string of random digits, as unique as your real fingerprint. But that would be extremely hard to recognise or share, so a string of random words is more suitable.